# Pasar múltiples valores a una ventana modal Yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

un placer, estoy trabajando con Yii2, y este es mi problema, tengo una lista de agencias, A cada agencia le he agregado un campo abono. Cuando una agencia realice un abono yo le agrego ese abono al campo, pero cuando yo coloque ese abono, debe de aparecer en una ventana modal y luego todos esos campos que le he agregado abonos deben de ser procesados, la pregunta para comenzar es, como hago para que esos campos y aparezcan en una sola ventana modal, y como tomar el ID de esa agencia y poderlo procesar.

```
 <?php foreach($concesionario as $conce){ ?>
 <tr>
   <td id="disket" align="center">
      <div class="input-group input-group-button">
         <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
            <?= $form->field($abonomodel, 'abono')->input('text', ['id' => 'abono'.$conce->pk_concesionario, 'data-a-sep' => '.', 'data-a-dec' => ',', 'class' => 'form-control form-control-right autonumber', 'style' => 'width:100%;height:27px;margin-bottom:-20px;'])->label(false); ?>
            <span class="input-group-addon" style="height: 27px;">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm waves-effect waves-light"/>
            <i class="icofont icofont-listing-box"></i> Abonar
            </button>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </td>
    </tr>
 <?php } ?>
```

Ventana Modal

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="detallesModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
             <h5 class="modal-title"><?= $nombreconcesionario->nombre; ?> <?= $nombreconcesionario->apellido; ?></h5>
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
             </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body p-b-0">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                   Dato agencia 1 <br>
                   Dato Agencia 2 <br>
                  Dato Agencia 3 <br>                                                  
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm waves-effect waves-light">Guardar</button>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hola @YoseiRomero, La verdad que no te entendí nada! Podrías poner una imagen con lo que esta cargando ahora y otra aunque sea editada en paint con lo que deseas obtener? De este modo se entenderá mas tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola, esta es la muestra, http://thcs.com.ve/descargas/ayuda1.png ingreso los datos en cada campo, y que cada campo que ingrese se me muestre en la ventana modal http://thcs.com.ve/descargas/ayuda2.png los datos son dinámicos, varían las agencias.

Comment: debes cargar los datos via ajax, al hacer clic en el modal haces la llamada ajax, traes los datos y los pintas en el modal